# Why is SliceDensityPlot3D leaving out sections that DensityPlot gets?

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

My program uses NDSolveValue to solve for a 3D function. The code is pretty hefty so I've pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/ghfREsWJ), and I'm just including the really relevant excerpts of it below.

Once I have my 3D function, `sol`, solved, I try plotting it on a `SliceDensityPlot3D`, from two different viewpoints and plotting plane (`{z == zmidpt}` and `{y == ymidpt}`). Here, plotting for `{x,y,z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]` should plot over the region outside of the two smaller rectangles in the box (I hope that's clear, let me know if it's not). However, to be safe, for one of the two plots below, I also plotted over the whole boxed region, which should also be fine:

```
Show[SliceDensityPlot3D[
  sol[x, y, z], {{z == zmidpt}}, {x, First@simxbds, Last@simxbds}, {y,
    First@simybds, Last@simybds}, {z, First@simzbds, 
   Last@simzbds}(*{x,y,z}\[Element]\[CapitalOmega]*), 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 5}], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0], wholeregion, Opacity[0], lrectregion, 
   Opacity[0], rrectregion}, ImageSize -> Large]]

Show[SliceDensityPlot3D[
  sol[x, y, 
   z], {{y == ymidpt}(*,{z\[Equal]zmidpt}*)}, {x, y, 
    z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ViewPoint -> {0, -5, 0}], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0], wholeregion, Opacity[0], lrectregion, 
   Opacity[0], rrectregion}, ImageSize -> Large]]
```

Which produces:

[image]

[image]

This is pretty puzzling to me. As you can see, for the first one, where it should actually be plotting over the whole plane, it has those weird white curved areas outside the rectangles. In the second one, you can see that it's actually going *into* the rectangles, which it shouldn't, because $\Omega$ is actually everything *but* those rectangles. I thought that maybe there was something weird going on with the function, like it was undefined at those areas where it's white, so I just did a regular `DensityPlot` and `Plot3D` to check, using the same constant coordinates I did for the above ones:

```
Print@Row@{Plot3D[
     sol[x, y, zmidpt], {x, First@simxbds, Last@simxbds}, {y, 
      First@simybds, Last@simybds}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
    DensityPlot[
     sol[x, y, zmidpt], {x, First@simxbds, Last@simxbds}, {y, 
      First@simybds, Last@simybds}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> Black, 
     ImageSize -> Medium]};
Print@Row@{Plot3D[
     sol[x, ymidpt, z], {x, First@simxbds, Last@simxbds}, {z, 
      First@simzbds, Last@simzbds}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
    DensityPlot[
     sol[x, ymidpt, z], {x, First@simxbds, Last@simxbds}, {z, 
      First@simzbds, Last@simzbds}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> Black, 
     ImageSize -> Medium]};
```

Which gives:

[image]

Which all look pretty continuous and well defined. If you notice, I set `ClippingStyle->Black` so it would be visible if there were a weird clipping issue, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

edit: I am a fool. I was doing `PlotRange->All`, when you need to do `PlotRange->{All,All,All}` apparently. Here's what it looks like now:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Altho I've marked this as a dupe, I think you should still send a report that maybe `PlotRange -> All` should also be doing what `PlotRange -> {All, All, All}` does.